# Detox React Native end to end test is not running when app is close

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, detox

Currently doing some e2e using detox in react native. I'm trying to run detox without the emulator open but i can't make it run at the moment. Does anyone know why? I works well when the simulator is open.

I would really appreciate your thoughts guys thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to run your tests in android emulator in headless mode(without GUI)
In your detox configuration file, inside your device section, include the `headless` key and set it to true.

```
devices: {
    emulator: {
      type: 'android.emulator',
      headless: true,
      device: {
        avdName: emulator,
      },
    },
  }
```

for more information, please refer to the device section in detox config docs: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md

Answer (score 1):

this possibility just working in android not working in ios:
Optional. Boolean. Supported by android.emulator only.
False by default. When set to true, it tells Detox to boot an Android emulator with -no-window option